# Qt Q_INVOKABLE across threads

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to call Q_INVOKABLE functions from QML with a backend that is in another thread?
I've tried and the function is running in the GUI thread.
If i emit a signal in the Q_INVOKABLE function, the slot is running in the right thread.
This is my code:

```
//support_reader.hpp
class SupportReader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    SupportReader();

    Q_INVOKABLE void function();

  signals:
    void selfFunction();
};

//support_reader.cpp
SupportReader::SupportReader()
{
  qDebug() << "Constructor" << QThread::currentThread();
  QThread* t = new QThread;
  QObject::connect(t, &QThread::started, this, [](){ qDebug() << "Thread started" << QThread::currentThread(); });
  QObject::connect(this, &SupportReader::selfFunction, this, [](){ qDebug() << "Self function" << QThread::currentThread(); });
  moveToThread(t);

  t->start();
}

void SupportReader::function()
{
  qDebug() << "function" << QThread::currentThread();
  emit selfFunction();
}
```

This way everithing is working fine, but, is this a good idea?

Comment: This example in itself seems no problem. However, I think it will become more complex if you want to emit changes to properties. Are you planning to do so?

Comment: @Amfasis no, I only have to call a function from QML to a cpp thread

Comment: Ok, then this construct is fine. And just for completeness (for others): when wanting to emit changes to properties I'd also do a double signal to cross thread boundaries

Comment: Signals and Slots across threads can get messed up if not implemented correctly. I recommend giving [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) a good read.

Comment: Further reading: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52219114/16586783), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20657963/16586783), [3](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43230)